# Select all text in UITextField BUT without the little edit draggers?

Tags: ios

I would like to achieve a selected text like in the picture below.

[image: example]

But all existing answers use selectAll(nil) which displays this instead. See the little edit draggers ? I don't want them. Is that possible ?

[image]